# Orthonormal bases and the spectral theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Let $m, n \in N$. Prove that for any linear transformation $T: R^n \rightarrow R^m$ there exists an orthonormal basis $U = (\vec{u_1},...,\vec{u_n})$ of $R^n$ such that for all $1 \leq i,j  \leq n$, if $i \neq j$ then $T(\vec{u_i}) • T(\vec{u_j}) = 0$.

There was a hint that recommended I use the Spectral Theorem, but I'm totally stumped. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diagonalize $T^*T$ to obtain an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $u_1,\ldots, u_n$. Then write $T^*Tu_j = \lambda_j u_j$ for some coefficients $\lambda_j$. Then $$\langle Tu_i,Tu_j\rangle = \langle T^*Tu_i, u_j\rangle = \lambda_i \langle u_i,u_j\rangle = 0$$if $i \neq j$.

Comment: The diagonalization of $T^{T}T$ would be the diagonal matrix where the diagonal entries are $_1, ..., _m$, right?

Comment: Yes. $\phantom{}$

Comment: How do we know the basis of vectors constructed by diagonalizing $T^TT$ is orthonormal?

Comment: That's the content of the real spectral theorem. If you have a self-adjoint operator in a real inner product space, there is an orthonormal basis of the space consisting of eigenvalues for the operator. We apply this for $T^*T$.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: You can give a direct proof that for a self-adjoint operator, eigenvectors associated to different eigenvalues are automatically orthogonal, though. (It is a one line computation)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take $U$ to be an orthonormal basis of eigenvalues of $T^\top T$.